# Adding Existing column at the end of another column within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file extracted from a pdf file it contains 6 columns of which 2 columns are repeated thrice in such a way that :

```
S       D         S      D          S     D

1       A         3      C           5     E

2       B        4      D           6     F
```

Now I wanted to join them into a single column like this :

```
S      D

1      A

2      B

3      C

4      D

5      E

6      F
```

Anyone please help me on how to do this using pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would concatenate values at numpy level to not be bored by the column names:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df.iloc[:, i:i+2].values 
                                      for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2)]),
                      columns = df.columns[:2])
```

With this dataframe:

```
   S  D  S.1 D.1  S.2 D.2
0  1  A    3   C    5   E
1  2  B    4   D    6   F
```

it gives:

```
   S  D
0  1  A
1  2  B
2  3  C
3  4  D
4  5  E
5  6  F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the dataframes like this:

```
dframes = [A,B,C,D,E,F]
newdframe = pd.concat(dframes)
```

Comment: They are not dataframes, columns within a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Since your data have repeated column names, you can use `pandas.concat`:

```
pd.concat(df.iloc[:,i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(df.columns),2))
```

Output:

```
   S  D
0  1  A
1  2  B
0  3  C
1  4  D
0  5  E
1  6  F
```